# Convert a select drop down into a <ul> list and have the selected category highlighted

Tags: jquery, html-lists, html-select

I have the following "Filter" `select` dropdown menu

```
<select name="sPhrase" id="sPhrase" class="filter">
    <option value="bothlevel">BOTH LEVELS</option>
    <option value="xplorelevel">XPLORE LEVEL</option>
    <option value="xcellevel">XCEL LEVEL</option>
</select>
<input value="GO" class="submit" type="submit">
```

which I have converted into an `ul` list and made the select drop down invisible with css

```
<ul class="list">
    <li><a href="#" data-value="bothlevel">BOTH LEVELS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="xplorelevel">XPLORE LEVEL</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="xcellevel">XCEL LEVEL</a></li>
</ul>
<input value="GO" class="submit" type="submit">
```

using the following jQuery code

```
$('select.filter').after('<ul class="list"></ul>');
$('select.filter option').each(function () {
$('ul.list').append('<li><a href="#" data-value="'
                     + $(this).val() + '">' 
                     + $(this).text()
                     + '</a></li>');
});

// set active to selection and sync

// update dropdown when links selected
$('ul.list > li > a').click(function(){
    $('ul.list > li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    var e =  $(this).parent().index();
    $('select.filter option:eq('+e+')').prop('selected', true);

});
// update list when dropdown selected
$('select.filter').change(function() {
    var e =  $('option:selected', this).index();
    $('ul.list > li').removeClass('active');
    $('ul.list > li:eq('+e+')').addClass('active');
});
```

However the issue is, when a category is selected/clicked from the ul list, and the submit button is clicked, once the page refreshes, the ul list not longer highlights the previously selected category.

Any ideas to still have the category highlighted after the page has loaded the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if we consider Dropdown list has the correct value after refreshing page, you can set them on dom ready like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var e =  $('select.filter option:selected').index();
    $('ul.list > li:eq(' + e + ')').addClass('active');
});
```